# Where to place config file in blazor client

Tags: c#, configuration, root, blazor, configuration-files

I have a `Blazor` browser-side project and i am trying to use a configuration `json` file in order to set some things up.
I do not understand where to place this config file in order to use it later on.
So my folder structure is :

**Folder schema when publishing**

```
-root  //tried placing the json here
  - [Blazor server's dll's]
  - Client
    -dist   //tried placing the json here
      -framework/
      -css/
      -index.html
```

**Client**

```
public class Startup {
        public static Config config;
        public static Action<IServiceCollection> ConfigureServicesForDebugging { get; set; }
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
            ConfigureServicesForDebugging?.Invoke(services);
            services.AddSingleton<AdminService>();
            Console.WriteLine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()); //renders /
            var config = File.ReadAllText("conf.json");

        }

        public void Configure(IBlazorApplicationBuilder app) {
            app.AddComponent<App>("app");
        }
    }
```

I just want to be able to read that configuration file inside the `Client` project and i do not know how.It can't find it.
I tried to print and see the `Console.WriteLine(Directory.CurrentDirectory)` but i would get the relative path.

How can i find the current directory of my blazor application in order to retrieve the configuration for the Client project ?

**Update**

**Usage**
I have a couple of  html forms where i bind some html attributes like the `action` to some config file value:

```
class Config
{
   public string FormUrl{get;set;}
}
```

**Blazor Form**

```
<form action=config.FormUrl>
<input type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

@functions()
{
   [Parameter] protected Config config{get;set;}
}
```

I assume i need to have this `Config` resolved in the `Startup` somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not really about the 'where', all files are relative to wwwroot, like images etc.

But it is about *how* you read a file. File.ReadAllText() probably throws, it is not supported from a browser.

You can take a leaf from the /fetchdata sample page: use HttpClient.

I whipped up a sample but I couldn't get anything working in the Startup class. I guess that essential parts (like the HttpClient) are not configured yet.

So you can read the config from your main page, or implement it in App.razor :

```
@inject HttpClient Http

<Router AppAssembly="typeof(Program).Assembly">
    <NotFoundContent>
        <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
    </NotFoundContent>
</Router>

@code
{
    protected override async Task OnInitAsync()
    {            
        string json = await Http.GetStringAsync("/conf.json");
        Console.WriteLine(json);            
    }
}
```

this reads `wwwroot/conf.json`

Comment: I have multiple  blazor components that use a service which is constructed using the `json` file.Is there no way i can create this service in the `Startup` ? I basically need to read the `json` before i init my blazor components.

Comment: No, you can get a HttpClient in Configure() but calling it hangs the app, I think because it needs `.Result`. We need a ConfigureAsync() . Getting it in ConfigureServices() is not an option for what I can tell.

Comment: So, how hard do you need it in Startup?  It's usually possible to delay loding stuff until the first use.

Comment: Well i have a couple of `Components` and some of them are `html forms` where i bind the `action` attribute to some configuration value.I really need them from the start.I have updated my initial post.

Comment: Would this be easily accessed by any other software on the user's machine?

Comment: Looks like the method is now OnInitializedAsync instead of OnInitAsync. Anyone know if this is a best practice to do the config this way?